How to deal with a dataset with low feature importance?
I have a dataset whose feature importance lists descendingly as 0.25, 0.16, 0.11, 0.08, 0.05, followed by many features with 0 importance, and the importance drops dramatically. Although the total importance adds up to 0.99(for obvious reason), since except for these top 5 features listed above, all others have a rather low importance fluctuating around 0.01, which is not that supportive, but removing these non-zero important features would decrease model's general performance, so keeping only the best features do not seem like a wise way.
How can we remedy this situation?

How are you measuring feature importance? And what model are you using? And what are the total number of features?

Have you tried keeping just the top10 features? How much does performance drop?

I measured feature importance using scikit learn's random forest's built-in feature importance attribute. I have about 40 features, but half of them have a less than 0.01 importance so i guess they dont contribute too much, most of the importance comes from the top 20 features, the highest importance is 0.25, and like i mentioned in the main post, the following importance drop significantly to 0.16 for the 2nd place, 0.1 for the 3rd, and 0.05~0.03 for the rest of top 20 features. The top 10 features would add up to about 0.6 importance, which is not quite convincing..

Why is it "not convincing"? Have you actually tried dropping them - how much does performance actually drop?

RandomForest feature importance has several issues that can cause misleading results. Especially with correlated features (very common): https://explained.ai/rf-importance/

It is not convincing in the sense that the sum importance of all >0.05 importance features is about 0.65, and the rest of 0.35 is contributed by many small variables with less than 0.01 importance, which makes me think if this indiciates my "major" features, aka top 5/10 depending on preference, is not good enough.

Feature importance scores from RF are not linear with predictive performance. It may be that you cut 0.5 of scores, but predictive performance barely changes at all. This is something that one has to try.

@JonNordby I tried that as well, I dropped those least important features and the performance (r2, for example) dropped 0.1~0.2

If you want a better feature importance that is more predictive of, use permutation importance (as mentioned in previous link about the problems of RF feature importance)    https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/permutation_importance.html

@JonNordby thank you that was helpful! I tried permutation importance and it does produce some different result, although I wonder why all these mean importances are 0, 0.1, or 0.2 for some reasons, and their total importance is higher than 1. I did some research on the second question, it appears to be related with poor model performance like low r2, but my model has been performing very well with a fluctuating r2 between 0.85 and 0.7, so im still kind of confused...
